# Asp.Net how to apply a css style to all the control of it's kind

Tags: asp.net, css, controls

I want to use a css style that will apply to all the control of it's kind.

```
.(Kind of Control)

{
  css propeties;
}
```

How can I do it ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for textbox:

```
[type=text]
{
    css propeties;
}
```

for text area

```
textarea 
{ 
    css propeties;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to approach this differently, in that you need to set up a skin of the control type and apply a CSS to it.

There is more detail on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.ASPx)

Also, on the link above you can review Themes which may also be helpful.

> Themes are similar to cascading style sheets in that both themes and
>   style sheets define a set of common attributes that can be applied to
>   any page. However, themes differ from style sheets in the following
>   ways:
>
> Themes can define many properties of a control or page, not just style properties. For example, using themes, you can specify the
>   graphics for a TreeView control, the template layout of a GridView
>   control, and so on.
>
> Themes can include graphics.
>
> Themes do not cascade the way style sheets do. By default, any property values defined in a theme referenced by a page's Theme
>   property override the property values declaratively set on a control,
>   unless you explicitly apply the theme using the StyleSheetTheme
>   property. For more information, see the Theme Settings Precedence
>   section above.
>
> Only one theme can be applied to each page. You cannot apply multiple themes to a page, unlike style sheets where multiple style
>   sheets can be applied.

However:

> "A theme can also include a cascading style sheet (.css file). When
>   you put a .css file in the theme folder, the style sheet is applied
>   automatically as part of the theme. You define a style sheet using the
>   file name extension .css in the theme folder."

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to apply a css to all labels, just type;

```
label
{
 css propeties;
}
```

note: use html control names to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the styles even without specifying the CssClass="YourStyle" property just like below example.

```
<style type="text/css">
[type=textarea]
{
    css propeties;
}

</style>
```